# Preprocess before kendo ui upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, kendo-ui

I want to pass some data(a guid) to the upload method of the kendoUpload so that the particular MVC Controller action method will receive that data. Each time the upload happens, I need to pass this data (guid).

```
$("#propertyAttachmentUpload").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: fileUploadUrl,
                chunkSize: 1048576,
                removeUrl: "remove"
            },
            multiple: true,
            upload: function (e) {
                e.data = { id: $("#fileUplpderParentObjectId").val(), fileId: fileId };
            },
            showFileList: false,
            dropZone: ".propertyAttachmentDropZone",
            success: onSuccess
        });
```

The field is `fileId`. I can call the above code block in a click event of the upload button and it works but the Kendo UI styles are not applied to the upload button at the initialization.

```
$("#propertyAttachmentUpload").click(
    function() {
        var fileId = guid();
        $("#propertyAttachmentUpload").kendoUpload({
            async: {
                saveUrl: fileUploadUrl,
                chunkSize: 1048576,
                removeUrl: "remove"
            },
            multiple: true,
            upload: function (e) {
                e.data = { id: $("#fileUplpderParentObjectId").val(), fileId: fileId };
            },
            showFileList: false,
            dropZone: ".propertyAttachmentDropZone",
            success: onSuccess
        });
    });
```

How can I initialize the fileId without loosing the Kendo UI styles.

Note: I cannot call `guid()` inside `upload` method since the upload method calls for each uploading chunk. For all the chunks the fileId should be same for a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem using a global variable and setting that variable in the click event of the upload button,

```
var fileGuid = '';

$(document).on('click', '#propertyAttachmentUpload', function() {
    fileGuid = "";
    fileGuid = guid();
})

$("#propertyAttachmentUpload").kendoUpload({
    async: {
        saveUrl: fileUploadUrl,
        chunkSize: 1048576,
        removeUrl: "remove"
    },
    multiple: true,
    upload: function (e) {
        e.data = { id: $("#fileUplpderParentObjectId").val(), fileId: fileGuid };
    },
    showFileList: false,
    dropZone: ".propertyAttachmentDropZone",
    success: onSuccess
});
```